# Upgrade with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am converting a website over to ASP.NET 2.0, which supports .NET Framework versions 2.0 – 3.5. I am getting the following error message on a particular tab that is connected to a SQL DB. I am stuck at where this change needs to occur as I did not build this particular section of the site. Here is the error message and the Code. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
MagicAjax.AjaxCallHelper.GetPageHiddenDictionary(Page page, String fieldName) +37
MagicAjax.AjaxCallHelper.HandleClientScriptBlocks(Page page, Boolean 
reflectToClient)      +17
MagicAjax.AjaxCallHelper.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) +238
System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +8996626
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 
includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: If you're going to convert the code from classic ASP to .Net you should go with the latest. While it's good that you provided the stack trace, we need the code that is being called to generate this. Try running it in debug mode (hit the `F5` key). Then update this with more code. It looks like either the `Page` or the fieldName isn't being passed in. You need to find out what that tab requires in order to rock out it's SQL love

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?